# Bring UIScrollView to foreground

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UIScrollView inside a cell but when the cell is selected the view disappears in the background how can I put it back to foreground. Thanks

JVPython

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible you aren't properly setting up your UITableViewCell so that selection doesn't cover up the cell contents. Perhaps you are adding the scrollview to the cell directly and not to the contentView of the cell?

The Apple documentation describes the layout of a cell and what happens to those elements when a cell is selected: [Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html)

Comment: I made the custom cell in Interface Builder by dragging each component in the content view

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:myScrollerView];
```

Comment: what is the view the scrollView sits on?

Comment: Its directly on the cells content view